# angularJS: condition in templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

I have following template in Backbone and i want to use the same template  in angularJs.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;float:left;">
        <% _(flights).each(function(flight){%>
            <span><%=flight.code%> <%=flight.number%></span>
        <% if(flight.id!= flights[flights.length-1].id) {%> 
            <span> / </span>
        <%} }); %>
    </div>
```

Following is my AngularJS template

```
<ul id="flightlist" style="list-style-type:none;-webkit-padding-start:0px;" ng-model="selectedFlight">
    <li ng-repeat="f in directFlights" value="{{f.id}}"  >

        <div style="height:50px;border:2px solid black;border-radius:25px;padding:10px;margin:10px;" id="flight0">
            <div style="display: inline-block;float:left;">
                <span>{{f.value.code }}-{{f.value.number}}</span>           
            </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;float:right;">
                    <div>
                        <lable>Depart</lable>                           
                        <lable>{{f.value.depart.scheduledtime}}</lable> 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <lable>Arrive</lable>                           
                        <lable>{{f.value.arrive.scheduledtime}}</lable> 
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to check for <% if(flight.id!= flights[flights.length-1].id) {%>  in angularJS

Comment: Checkout the `ng-if` directive, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of ng-if directive

```
<div ng-if="flight.id!= flights[flights.length-1].id">
--Show something--
</div>
```

ng-if can works on the complex expressions too !!